# Android - ListView is not updated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Someone please explain why when I save the application settings (SharedPreferences) after dialog (AlertDialog),and update the data in the ListAdapter's item the following way `mListItems.get(viewPosition).setValue(prefsIntValue);` (`mListItems` - is the member of main activity). after closing dialog window **the view in the ListView is updated**, and when I try to do the same thing in the method `onActivityResult` ( update the data on the completion of the other activity) , nothing happens, in other words, **view is not updated.** kind of an answer is here [notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example), but then why does the first case ( after the dialog box ) work!?

**UPD:** Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` after I changed list data in `onActivityResult` method helped! But please, someone, explain why in the first case, when saving preferences, it worked?!

Comment: It sounds like a context issue. If you post some code we can help you out.

Comment: did you try the runOnUiThread method?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, because method `onWindowFocusChanged` http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#2646 called after I close AlertDialog window, the layout list view is being redrawn by calling `layoutChildren` in the method above in which happens all the magic.